# Prove $f(x) = x^3+a $ is bijective for any fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$ by proving the existence of a surjective inverse function $f^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, inverse-function

I know the property:   If $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a bijection, $f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ for any $y\in \mathbb R$ **(i)**.

I think that is equivalent to:

If there exist an surjective inverse function $f^{-1}: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ of $f$ with
$f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ for any $y\in \mathbb R$, then $f$ is a bijection **(ii)**.

**Statement:**

$f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R, f(x) = x^3+a $ is bijective for any fixed $a\in \mathbb{R}$

**Proof:**

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed but arbitrary.
Define $f^{-1}: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ as  $ f^{-1}(y)=(y-a)^{\frac13}$.

The function $f^{-1}$ is surjective because $ (y-a)^{\frac13}$ exists for every $y\in\mathbb R$ and $f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$.

$\overset{(ii)}{\Rightarrow}$ $f$ is a bijection

### Edit

**I want to prove it explicitly in the way I did (if my method is correct).**

Comment: That's just fine. You have explicitly calculated the inverse function.

Comment: it could be nice to mention that you have $f^{-1}(f(y))=y$ (which is true) to ensure infectivity or 1-1ness as well. Otherwise it looks fine. As a function is onto if it has a right inverse, and you've shown it has a right inverse only. To be a bijection you need left and right inverse.

Comment: The proof is fine but I prefer to do it the following way: solve the equation $f(x)= y$ ($y$ is given,  $x$ is unknown). If there is a unique solution $x$ we are done and we can write $x=f^{-1}(y).$ In your case $x^3+a=y.$ Hence $x^3=y-a$ and consequently $x=(y-a)^{1/3}.$

Comment: Cherry, the reason why the function $f^{-1}\!:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is surjective is that for any $x\in\Bbb R$ there exists $y\in\Bbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(y)=x$. But you wrote the function $f^{-1}$ is surjective because $(y-a)^{\frac13}$ exists for every $y\in\mathbb R$ and it is not correct indeed it only means that $f^{-1}$ is defined on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @MyMathYourMath, to be $f$ a bijection, we do not necessarily need both left and right inverse, indeed it is sufficient a surjective right inverse. Look at my answer.

Comment: Cherry, if you are interested in the proof of the property **(ii)**, look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Statement:**

Let $A,B$ two nonempty sets and let $\,f:A\to B\,$ be a function.
If there exists a surjective function $\;g:B\to A\;$ such that $\;f[g(y)]=y\;$ for any $\;y\in B\;,\;$ then $\,f:A\to B\,$ is a bijection.

**Proof:**

The function $\;f:A\to B\;$ is surjective, indeed for any $\;y\in B\;$ there exists $\;x=g(y)\in A\;$ such that $\;f(x)=f[g(y)]=y\;.$

Now, we will prove that $\;f:A\to B\;$ is injective too.
Let $\;x_1,\,x_2\in A\;$ such that $\;f(x_1)=f(x_2)\;.$
Since $\;g:B\to A\;$ is a surjective function, then there exist $\,y_1,\,y_2\in B\;$ such that $\;g(y_1)=x_1\;$ and $\;g(y_2)=x_2\;,\;$ hence ,
$y_1=f[g(y_1)]=f(x_1)=f(x_2)=f[g(y_2)]=y_2\;$ and
$x_1=g(y_1)=g(y_2)=x_2\,.$
We have just proved that $\;x_1,x_2\!\in\!A,\,f(x_1)\!=\!f(x_2)\Rightarrow x_1\!=\!x_2$
i.e. $\;f:A\to B\;$ is injective.

Consequently, $\;f:A\to B\;$ is a bijection because it is injective and surjective.

**Addendum:**

Under the same hypotheses of the Statement, we can also prove that the function $\;g:B\to A\;$ is a bijection too and $\;g=f^{-1}.$

**Proof:**

Let $\;y_1,\,y_2\in B\;$ such that $\;g(y_1)=g(y_2)\;.$
It results that $\;y_1=f[g(y_1)]=f[g(y_2)]=y_2\;.$
We have just proved that $\;y_1,y_2\!\in\!B,\,g(y_1)\!=\!g(y_2)\Rightarrow y_1\!=\!y_2$
i.e. $\;g:B\to A\;$ is injective.
Consequently, $\;g:B\to A\;$ is a bijection because it is injective and surjective.
Let $\;f^{-1}:B\to A\;$ be the inverse function of $\;f:A\to B\;.$
Since $\;f[g(y)]=y=f[f^{-1}(y)]\;$ for any $\;y\in B\;,\;$ then
$g(y)=f^{-1}(y)\;$ for any $\;y\in B\;,\;$ i.e. $\;g=f^{-1}.$